# How does plant size and shape change with different levels of light?

Tags: light

For a plant species that is described as "full sun to full shade", what differences might I expect to see if I plant it in full sun vs full shade? If you need a specific example plant, I'm writing this because I'm trying to place an American Hazelnut (*Corylus americana*) - but would love more general answers if they can be had.

I know fruiting plants will usually bear more with more sun. But beyond that...

- Will plants also flower less?
- I assume they have less energy to grow, but does that make them grow slower or just get leggy like a houseplant reaching for a window?
- Will the overall form of the plant be less compact in shade?
- Will the mature size be less in shade? More? About the same? If different, by how much?

Note that I'm not asking about things like susceptibility to drought, leaf burn - gardening sites are usually pretty good about putting that in their plant profiles if it's a risk. I specifically want to know, assuming I care for the plant properly, whether and how a plant will look significantly different in my garden depending on how much sun it gets.